# pick condition from column values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to write an effective query instead of a loop and I have following data.

```
table : market_symbol 

symbolid condition 
10001    type=1
20001    country='IN'
```

function: `fetch_symbol_data(symbolid)`

function returns:

`symbolid , type, country`

I want to fetch all symbol data that are available in table market_symbol from  function fetch_symbol_data 
like this

```
select b.* 
from market_symbol a 
cross apply dbo.fetch_symbol_data(a.symbolid) b
```

this is working fine but I want to use a condition column as well in single query to fetch data on the basis of condition specified in condition column.

please suggest.

Comment: What you are looking for is dynamic SQL, and this is very hard to put into the framework you have set up.

Comment: its not clear for me how symbolid and condition are currently related. is it not true that a symbol can have both (more) attributes, like 10001 has a value for "country", and a "type" value as well? especially given your sample data, what would the function return for symbol 10001 as the country? easiest solution is probably to get rid of those condition expressions stuffed into a varchar column, and make a standard key-value-bag schema first.

Comment: Fetch_symbol_data has all the data but i want data only for symbol that i am passing from column symbolid of market_symbol table and condition that i am passing from condition column from market_symbol.

Using cross apply i am able to pass first thing but to restrict data on the basis of condition column i could not do that.